# How to extract consonant / vowels groups from a word ?

Tags: regex, language-agnostic

I would like to wrote a regex that split a  word into cvc (consonant/vowel/consonant) or vcv groups. Something similar to ngrams but using voyels and consonants. Here is an example :

```
helloworld
```

would produce the following groups :

```
hell
ello
llow
owo
world
```

I have wrote the following regex :

```
(?=(([aeiouy]+|[^aeiouy]+){3}))
```

The first part `([aeiouy]+|[^aeiouy]+){3}` capture either a vcv or cvc group, the rest `(?=(  ))` is a positive lookahead assertion.
It doesn't work as expected :

```
hell
ello
llow
low //owo expected
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you use a lookahead alone, characters are not consumed, and the parser tries all positions in the string (in other words, it is not able to jump more than one character at a time).

You can solve the problem like this:

```
(?=((?:[aeiou]+|[b-dfghj-np-tv-z]+){3}))(?:[aeiou]+|[b-dfghj-np-tv-z]+)
```

[demo](https://regex101.com/r/hk1Suh/1)

Now the leading vowels (or consonants) are consumed for each match (outside of the lookahead).

Comment: So the this part `(?:[aeiou]+|[b-dfghj-np-tv-z]+)` will force the engine to consume a group of voyels or consonants before matching next cvc or vcv group. I think i got it. Question : is it better performance wise to match consonants the way you did (by explicitly specifying them) vs how i did it (by saying it's everything but not vowels) ?

Comment: @tigrou: I don't think there's a big difference.

Answer (score 0):

By putting all patterns into lookahead part you make it non-greedy in choosing a start match point. Use one explicit and two lookahead V/C sequence instead:

```
r = re.compile('(?:([aeiouy]+)(?=([^aeiouy]+[aeiouy]+)))|(?:([^aeiouy]+)(?=([aeiouy]+[^aeiouy]+)))')
```

Then simply concatenate the groups

```
map (lambda l:''.join(l), re.findall(r,"Helloworld"))
```